# Converting long integer into date and time in r

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I have date and time information in the following format:

```
z <- 20201019083000
```

I want to convert it into a readable date and time format such as follows:

```
"2020-10-19 20:20"
```

So far I have tried this but cannot get the correct answer.

#in  local

```
as.POSIXct(z, origin = "1904-01-01")
"642048-10-22 14:43:20 KST"
```

#in UTC

```
as.POSIXct(z, origin = "1960-01-01", tz = "GMT")
"642104-10-23 05:43:20 GMT"
```

#in

```
 as.POSIXct(as.character(z), format = "%H%M%S")
    "2021-07-13 20:20:10 KST"
```

Any better way to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't you want `20201019083000` to convert to `"2020-10-19 20:30"`, and not `20:20`?

Comment: I assumed the 083000 part is time, and when I convert it manually in excel it was 20:20. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms("20201019083000")
# [1] "2020-10-19 08:30:00 UTC"

# or, format the output:
format(ymd_hms("20201019083000"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
# "2020-10-19 08:30"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `as.POSIXct` or `strptime` with the format `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`:

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(z), format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
#[1] "2020-10-19 08:30:00 CEST"

strptime(z, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
#[1] "2020-10-19 08:30:00 CEST"
```

Your tried format `"%H%M%S"` dos not include *Year* `%Y` , *Month* `%m` and *Day* `%d`.